# White space under expandable List View, how to make it disappear?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I tried to enlarge the **`ListView`** to make it fill the screen , but no way.
here is the layout code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.0">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewweight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewdrug"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.919"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewdrug"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.095"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/idListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/graymillidos"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

is there any mistakes in my code ?

and here is the result :

[image: my app layout]

Comment: can you share your whole layout

Comment: Can you share your parent and child layouts ?

Comment: have you try add android:fillViewport="true" for ExpandableListView?

Comment: Now you can see the whole layout, I edited the question.

Comment: It will only show you the amount of items you have. So fillViewport wont work here. You will have to increase the size of your item view.